# dll file dependency mess with nuget packagereference

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Our team provides multiple nuget SDKs for users to refer to. Every nuget file we created will contain its own project dll file and its dependency dll files.

This caused us problem when users try to use more than one nuget sdks. Especially when those nugets contain different version of same dll dependency.

For example, nuget A contains a.dll. nuget B(depends on nuget A) contains both a.dll and b.dll because of dependency auto parsing. If users add reference to both nuget A and B, and when there is any change in a.dll, we need to update both nuget A and B and ask our use to update to lastest nuget A and B at the same time.

This has caused us lots of trouble when amount of nugets we own increases. And every time we make some changes we have to update all nugets we support.
Is there any way we can limit one dll dependency to be only in one nuget? Then we only need to update one nuget when some update happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Every nuget file we created will contain its own project dll file and its dependency dll files.

That's the problem. Each NuPkg file should only contain its own libraries, but declare its dependencies on other packages. That's the default behavior when a NuPkg file is packed, so presumably you've got additional bits in either your .nuspec file or your .csproj file to include the dependency libraries... just remove those.

Once each package only contains its own library, you're back to the "expected" situation and clients should be able to just depend on one of them, and the tooling will resolve dependencies transitively.